# React Redux useState getting info from state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm using React type script NodeJS mySQL with Redux and building a vacation planner project.
I need to show all vacations via cards and need to have different elements on the card if it's an Admin or a user.

I use the useState to get the user state, and whenever I want to extract data from the user I get an error.
In the UserModel at the roleId I have RoleModel (enum with 'admi' = 1, 'user' = 2).
Example - VacationCard(props):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import UserModel from "../../../Models/UserModel";
import VacationModel from "../../../Models/VacationModel";
import { authStore } from "../../../Redux/AuthState";
import appConfig from "../../../Utils/Config";
import "./VacationCard.css";

 interface VacationCardProps {
    vacation: VacationModel;
 }

 function VacationCard(props: VacationCardProps): JSX.Element {

    // let users: UserModel = authStore.getState().user;

const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModel>();

useEffect(() => {
    setUser(authStore.getState().user);

    const unsubscribe = authStore.subscribe(() => {
        setUser(authStore.getState().user);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);

return (
    <div className="VacationCard">
        <div>
            {/* {user.roleId === 2} */}
            Destination: {props.vacation.destination}
            <br />
            Description: {props.vacation.description}
            <br />
            Check In: {props.vacation.checkIn}
            <br />
            Check Out: {props.vacation.checkOut}
            <br />
            Price: {props.vacation.price}
            <br />
            {user.roleId === 2 && <>Followers: {props.vacation.followersCount}</>}
            {/* {users.roleId === 2 && <>Followers: {props.vacation.followersCount}</>} 
    */}

        </div>

        <div>
            <img crossOrigin="anonymous" src={appConfig.vacationImagesUrl + 
             props.vacation.imageName} />
        </div>
    </div>
   );
  }

 export default VacationCard;
```

The first way of useState and user gives me an error, but the other way with user:UserModel works.
Should I stay with the useState or the other way?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd start by extracting any auth data-related logic to its own custom React hook and use it inside your component to fetch the user status off of that data. Then you can do conditional rendering based on the user status value. That would help extract all the stateful logic out of the component and keep it pure and free of side effects.

Comment: Can you write and example please? I will understand better that way, what you mean and will be able to write the extras on the correct places.